I have an illness

I have an illness.
It all started one day, although I only remember so much.
I remember I was in a nation which you'll recognize from a symbol of red and black, a legacy of what it left behind. Then I was in a state which is odd and repetitive in its year. Then in an island nation which's capital's first letter is also my disease's! And then in a country from the West which had the same case, as in my disease's name, but with the last letter of it! Next we have a nation which once had a crisis where two powers held alphabetically together had a rather large stake in it. I actually visited that twice! Next we have a specific zone in a much larger nation which claims to be at the center of the largest continent. And it all ended with me awaking in unknown walls in a war-torn nation, ruined by communists and capitalists alike, and now with an extremely totalitarian government, literally at the bottom. I made my way out of there fast.

This is what my patient said to me in our latest session, but this seems more like a puzzle, and I am not sure what to make of this. Can you help me on figuring out the disease?
(The resulting word is formed from the names of each nation.)
Hints:

 1. The West is defined as above the Tropic of Cancer.


 2. Out of the two powers, the name of one being referenced is not really it's true one, but from other countries people may commonly erroneously refer it to as such.


 3. The specific zone was once ruled by a foreign power, not the greatest power, but a great one. The power is from Europe.


Could people explain the downvote reasons?

Dunno about votes, but looks like the tags here are wrong. Can't see how it's related to geography, and it's missing the [tag:enigmatic-puzzle] tag as well.

@ShadowWizard It definitely is related to geography with some geographical requirements in there. This has the "word" tag, which means the result is a word that must be figured out. And the nations lead to that word. So how can then it be enigmatic?

Hello. Was the place you visited twice called 'Egypt'? Then, I can post an answer.

@M.Riyan rot13("Lrf. Lbh pna cbfg lbhe nafjre.");

I think the answer is:

typhoid

If I go through the clues, it says:
The first clue: a nation which you'll recognize from a symbol of red and black, a legacy of what it left behind.
I could not figure it out. It felt like Germany at the first thought, but I could not connect it with the name of the disease.
Coming to the next: I was in a state which is odd and repetitive in its year. I went through a reverse search of what the state could be [probably an American State] so that the letters in it fit in my answer, so I chose Ohio. But I still could not connect it to the clue.
The third: Then in an island nation which's capital's first letter is also my disease's. Considered it as

Japan, the capital being Tokyo.

Consequently, the fourth: And then in a country from the West which had the same case, as in my disease's name, but with the last letter of it. Found it to be

Iceland.

For the fifth: We have a nation which once had a crisis where two powers held alphabetically together had a rather large stake in it. I actually visited that twice!

 Egypt, so it seems.

In the sixth: Next we have a specific zone in a much larger nation which claims to be at the center of the largest continent.

 I am confused with it, I consider it to be Kazakhstan. The 3rd clue says The specific zone was once ruled by a foreign power, not the greatest power, but a great one. It felt like the foreign power is the Soviet Union.

Finally, the seventh is: And it all ended with me awaking in unknown walls in a war-torn nation, ruined by communists and capitalists alike, and now with an extremely totalitarian government. I made my way out of there fast.

Seems Korea. Especially, North Korea.

Final Toss:

 I found the disease to start with T, contain part of Egypt, or more precisely, yp in it, then ho from Ohio and id from Iceland. Is that a good approach?


Nice answer but not exactly. You're wrong on the last one, I'll add another clue to clarify that. Also a few things to nudge you in the right direction: Kazakhstan doesn't claim to be at the center of the largest continent. Repetition for the US. state has to do with dates. And hopefully whence you figure those out it should be easy to get the two countries remaining.

@192927376337929292283737373773 Rot13 (Jnf vg Puvan gura, ehyrq ol gur Zbatbyrf?). A yes or no would be much helpful. Thanks

Rot13("Vg vf va Puvan, ohg vg vf n fcrpvny nqzvavfgengvir ertvba. Lbh fubhyq abgr gung.");
